# How to await state change in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have spent the whole day searching through similar questions etc. but to no avail and I am losing my mind.

I am building a "translate app" using an API. In my Home functional component which is one of three in my bottom tab navigator, **I have these states:**

```
const [from, setFrom] = useState({language:'German', code:'ge_GE'});
const [to, setTo] = useState({language: 'English', code: 'en_GB'});
let [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [output, setOutput] = useState("");
const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])
```

There's a  `<TextInput>` with `onChange` handler to `setInput`.
I call `fetch()` as follows:

```
const fetch = () =>  {
    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
      setOutput(response.data.result);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setOutput("");
    });
  } 

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://lingvanex-translate.p.rapidapi.com/translate',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'lingvanex-translate.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
  },
  data: '{"from":"'+ from.code +'","to":"'+ to.code +'","data":"'+ input +'","platform":"api"}'
  };
```

The output then updates in my UI and **the wanted result in UI is achieved**.

**THE PROBLEM IS**: If I then use a button to save this translation to favorites with `saveHandler` on `onPress` prop like this:

```
function saveHandler(){
  const newFaves = [...favorites,{phrase: input, translation: output, source: from.code, target: to.code, key: favorites.length + 1 }];
    setFavorites(newFaves);
  }
```

After inspecting the latest favorite state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(favorites);
},[favorites])
```

I see that all the states have held their previous values while being supplied in `saveHandler`.

**I have seen similar issues on SO, people using second callback arguments, but I keep getting told by expo console that useState does not support it**. I am not really trying to turn to class components as I am absolutely lost after trying it. I believe there must be a way to do this. I ask you kind souls of SO, for your helping hand :(

**edit**: I understand such thing is achievable through useEffect, but I did not know how can I use this useEffect to "update its own dependency"...
I think I figured out a way but it seems it might cause performance issues.
After creating a non-state variable counterpart to every state, I can now do

```
useEffect(() => {
  hardOutput = output
},[output])
```

with saveHandler using the assigned non-state variable instead of state itself. Since I need to achieve this for four states, this seems to be lagging up the app, but is working somehow.

```
function saveHandler(){
  const newFaves = [...favorites,{phrase: hardInput, translation: hardOutput, source: hardFrom.code, target: hardTo.code, key: favorites.length + 1 }];
    setFavorites(newFaves);
  }
```

**edit 2**:
I found this article on stale closures https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/ and tried using the functional setState((previousState) => previousState = newState) but still got the same results.

**REPREX**:

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {  View, Text, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const axios = require("axios");

function Home() {
    const [from, setFrom] = useState({language:'Slovenčina', code:'sk_SK', key: 1});
    const [to, setTo] = useState({language: 'Angličtina', code: 'en_GB', key: 2});
    let [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [output, setOutput] = useState('')
    const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([{
    phrase: "Hello",
    translation: "Dobrý deň",
    source: "en_EN",
    target: "sk_SK",
    key: "1"
  }]);
 
const fetch = () =>  {
    axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    setOutput(response.data.result);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setOutput("");
    });
  } 

let saveButton = [];
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://lingvanex-translate.p.rapidapi.com/translate',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'lingvanex-translate.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
  },
  data: '{"from":"'+ from.code +'","to":"'+ to.code +'","data":"'+ input +'","platform":"api"}'
  };

function inputHandler(newText) {
  setInput(newText);
  setOutput("");
}

useEffect(() => {
    saveButtonHandler()
},[output])

function saveButtonHandler() {
saveButton= [];
saveButton.push(<TouchableOpacity onPress={saveHandler}>
  <Text>Save</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>);
}

function saveHandler(){
  const newFaves = [...favorites,{phrase: input, translation: output, source: from.code, target: to.code, key: favorites.length + 1 }];
    setFavorites(newFaves);
  }

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(favorites);
},[favorites])

return (
<TextInput 
value={input} 
onChangeText={inputHandler}/>
<Button title="Translate" onPress={translateHandler}>
{saveButton}
);
}
```

*Note: Functional component above is nested inside a tab navigation component nested inside main App function in App.js*

Comment: you don't await state changes, you use an effect (useEffect) that includes that state as a dependency. Then you it will execute the callback provided whenever that state changes.

Comment: Please post the code of the "*favorite dependent useEffect*" that you are having trouble with. Also show the context of `saveHandler` - where it is defined, how it is called, etc

Comment: "*creating a non-state variable counterpart to every state*" - no, don't do that. Your actual problem likely is that you use a stale closure of `saveHandler` somewhere, but we can't tell you how to properly fix this if you don't show us the complete code

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve] that demonstrates how clicking the button puts outdated values in the favourites?

Comment: @janetusim this question is very convoluted, and difficult to understand. It would help to simplify and remove unnecessary details. Why would you want to call setFavorites when favorites changes? That doesn't make sense

Comment: @JBaczuk I am not calling setFavorites at a favorite change. I am simply logging favorites at favorite change so I see the latest updated state of favorites, which show me that the states: input, output etc. that I saved in favorites are outdated. I wish I could narrow it down but I tried to follow the instructions given to me as closely as possible. I will try to do a rewrite

Comment: Ah, there's your problem: `saveButton.push(<TouchableOpacity onPress={saveHandler}>`. Don't create the button inside an effect! That stores an old version of the `saveHandler` inside the `saveButton` array. Drop that `useEffect` that depends on `output`, and instead simply render the `<TouchableOpacity>` (when `output` has a value) in the returned JSX.

Comment: @Bergi is there a ko-fi account I can donate to or anything I could do that would make your day as great as you just made mine kind sir?